# Overlapping DIV (Variable width issue)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div columns set to val%, within those columns I then have some smaller static width / height boxes ..

.. and on the other side a variable width / height column.

However as I vary the width of the browser window, these divs overlap.

I have tried various combinations of overflow / float / min and maximum heights etc but I am not getting anywhere.

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Rough jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2xdcases/

Actual Page:
https://www.ablueman.co.uk/testbench/newindex/

[image: screenshot]

```
.content {
margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BABABA;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: #b0c4de;
}

.cont {
float:left;
width:48%;
margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BABABA;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
/*background-color: #b0c4de;*/
/* min-height: 600px; */
}

.co {
float:left;
width: 200px;
Height: 300px;
margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
border: 1px solid #BABABA;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: JSfiddle is working fine in newest Safari on OS X

Comment: Did you try varying the width of the browser? its only when the left hand boxes pop from 3 columns to 2 or stretched out .. they overlap.

Comment: With your direct link I was able to reproduce the error. See my answer for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give #contentWrapper `overflow: hidden;`

Because the elements on the left are floated, the parent element will not change its size accordingly

For more information read this: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ (especially under the heading 'The great collapse')

Comment: Ahh.. I tried overflow:hidden; on all the classes, but actually had no css for that id. Perfect thanks!